# Improve function using loops (simple structure)

Tags: r, function, loops

I know this is probably a simple fix. I am looking to add a loop in the two functions below. I have a lot of trouble with loops. I think the basic structure is there; I am not seeing it, though. RptYr is a four-digit year (e.g., 2023).

```
AcaS_Sem <- function(RptYr) {
  AcaS_1 <- paste0("Spring", " ", RptYr - 1)
  AcaS_2 <- paste0("Fall", " ", RptYr - 2)
  AcaS_3 <- paste0("Summer", " ", RptYr - 2)
  AcaS_comb <- c(AcaS_1, AcaS_2, AcaS_3)
  print(AcaS_comb)
}
```

The second function is

```
Enroll_Dem <- function(RptYr) {
  Enroll_Dem_1 <- paste0("Fall", " ", RptYr)
  Enroll_Dem_2 <- paste0("Summer", " ", RptYr)
  Enroll_Dem_3 <- paste0("Spring", " ", RptYr)
  Enroll_Dem_4 <- paste0("Fall", " ", RptYr - 1)
  Enroll_Dem_5 <- paste0("Summer", " ", RptYr - 1)
  Enroll_Dem_6 <- paste0("Spring", " ", RptYr - 1)
  Enroll_Dem_7 <- paste0("Fall", " ", RptYr - 2)
  Enroll_vec <- c(Enroll_Dem_1, Enroll_Dem_2, Enroll_Dem_3, Enroll_Dem_4, 
                  Enroll_Dem_5, Enroll_Dem_6, Enroll_Dem_7)
  print(Enroll_vec)
}
```

Any insight will be most helpful. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You don't need a loop with either function. The first is just `AcaS_Sem <- function(RptYr) paste(c('Spring', 'Fall', 'Summer'), RptYr - c(1, 2, 2))`

Comment: Is this a special place on the planet where you live, or can you explain your logic 1.Fall, 2.Summer, 3.Spring?

Comment: Your second function could be `Enroll_Dem <- function(RptYr) paste(rep(c('Fall', 'Summer', 'Spring'), length.out = 7), RptYr - c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2))`

Comment: @jay.sf I'm guessing from the logic of the years being subtracted and the variable names that these are something like college semesters in reverse order.

Comment: Universities generally don't have winter, unless they are on a quarterly structure.

Comment: I agree that you don't need a loop here, but ... you say you want a simple fix, but what's the problem? How are you using these functions such that they don't work? For instance, `AcaS_Sem(1999:2000)` produces a length-6 string vector, alternating years. Is it the order you're trying to fix? (BTW, `paste0("A", " ", RptYr)` -> `paste0("A ", RptYr)` -> `paste("A", RptYr)`.)

Comment: Hello,  @Allan, yes, these are college semesters. Each file type is needed AcaS (Academic Standing) and Enroll (Enrollment) to construct the report I need. I need to go back a few years and determine the academic status (Freshman, Sophomore, etc). But these functions just tell me which reports I need to pull from the database, which is helpful because I only do that report once a year. Previously, all of this was done by hand.

Comment: @r2evans, was only looking for a smoother way to accomplish the task. The way I came up was rudimentary and clunky. but it did the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write a convenient function `f` for this job, which might also cover both tasks, you could `paste` a sequence together and extract a vector with certain start and stop values from it. Sth like

```
> f <- \(RptYr, from, to) {
+   len <- to/3
+   ssns <- c('Fall', 'Summer', 'Spring')
+   yrsq <- seq.int(RptYr, by=-1, length.out=len)
+   do.call('paste', expand.grid(ssns, yrsq))[from:to]
+ }
> RptYr <- 2023
> f(RptYr - 1, from=3, to=5)
[1] "Spring 2022" "Fall 2021"   "Summer 2021"
> f(RptYr, 1, 7)
[1] "Fall 2023"   "Summer 2023" "Spring 2023" "Fall 2022"   "Summer 2022" "Spring 2022" "Fall 2021"
```

Comment: What does the `do.call` function do?

Comment: @asokol `do.call(what, args)` allows evaluating a function by providing it's name (what) and a list of it's `arguments`. Since `expand.grid` throws a `data.frame` which is actually a list of two vectors (aka columns), we can conveniently `paste` these element-wise together.